# How MU-MIMO handles TxBF and transmitting multiple streams together?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, 802.11, 802.11ac

I have gone through a lot of references and most of it told like atleast 2 antennas are required to do TxBF, and with two different antennas either we can do TxBF by transmitting same streams or transmitting different streams of data, thereby doubling the throughput. For an 802.11ac AP with 4 antennas, it is also said by MU-MIMO in 802.11ac we can steer to 4 different single stream clients(1x1). Every illustration I saw is more like one antenna Transmitter is transmitting to a client.(for steering more than one antenna is required!!)

How is it possible that in MU-MIMO that it can generate 4 different spatial streams, and to individually beamform them, just with 4 antennas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MU-MIMO AKA second generation 802.11ac uses constructive interference
(also known as [wave superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle))

I'm assuming the illustrations you saw were for learning purposes and not necessarily scientifically accurate.

You can have 100 transmit antennas and 2 receive antennas, and that would still be a MIMO system. But you can only spatially multiplex two signals in this case.

MU-MIMO uses antenna and radio chains combined with a nice mathematical algorithm to determine where a physical client is located, then transmits out of the highest signal strength chain in conjunction with wave super-position principle mathematics to give the client direction superb signal strength, while using destructive interference in the opposite direction to cancel out the non-intended direction.

Note: i believe most of these products can negotiate what streams and radio chains they have available. a 1x1 stream seems to just be this (the radios report what the Best RSSI was out of the four antennas for the client, and then communicates to the client on that antenna.) you will notice on a lot of these routers, they have either directional, or semi-directional antennas on the router.

one stream cannot be controlled independently. That last stream, however, can be set to align with another stream, which can be used for multi-stream MIMO clients.  Thus, for the current generation of 4x4:4 MU-MIMO capable 802.11ac 2nd generation access points, the following combination of groups are valid:

(One 3x3:3 stream client device and one 1x1:1 stream client device.)

(Two 2x2:2 stream client devices)

(One 2x2:2 stream client device and up to two 1x1:1 stream client devices)

(Up to three 1x1:1 stream client devices.)
This type of access point can do conventional MIMO to one client, all the way up to a four-stream client device

This information was gathered mainly from this article, and a couple other sources.
https://www.networkcomputing.com/wireless-infrastructure/how-does-mu-mimo-work/748964231

Comment: Yeah, I agree to what you have said, but say for 4x4 system, can serve four different clients, or 4 streams, it can serve like 4 single stream clients at once. How is that possible because we have only 4 transmit chains, and to beamform atleast two antennas should be used. How it is able to transmit and beamform 4 streams simultaneously with the 4 antennas?

Comment: To answer your question, it cant. I edited the answer to reflect the question in your comment.

Comment: I got confused because in normal MIMO scenario, each antenna transmits single stream. While in MU-MIMO, it seems more like all the 4 streams are mixed before feeding it to the antennas, but same stream is given different phase shift in each of these antennas, so that they beamform in the direction of the respective client. The client has the knowledge of the steering matrix is able to filter out the signal intended for it.

Comment: If this has answered your question, please consider marking it answered. Thanks.